# Infopath people picker repeating field

Tags: infopath

Is it possible in Infopath 2013 to make the people picker a repeating field? As in, you put in one name and verify it, then another people picker box appears below it to put in another user, which then spawns another below it, and so on.

Comment: Could you provide a few more details please? Like, what are you trying to accomplish in this form and where/if this data is to be stored?

Comment: Basically i want to allow the person filling out the form to be able to enter as many users as they want, and then have the form trigger an email to each of them and store their names on a list item (or items)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution than having multiple People Picker fields would be to have just 1 field and allow multiple values (in properties). You then can send out emails when the form is submitted via Code Behind or an SharePoint Designer Workflow.